# How to install Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)?

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics, gpu-driver, ubuntu-drivers

I have sony vaio sb36FN which has two vga graphics cards: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M Series] and Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116]. I've installed AMD driver but not able to figure out how to install intel graphics controller. As due to the incorrect installation of drivers the system get heats up and which may further lead to damage to other devices connected to the motherboard. Please suggest me how to check the installed drivers on the system and also the procedure to install same.

Answer (score 0):

According to [HybridGraphics Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/HybridGraphics) you have to use the ATI control panel to switch between graphics cards. Unfortunately, it's not as seamless as Windows configuration. But, as you probably know, things in Linux rare are ;)

If I'm not mistaken (and I may be, I'm not an X11 guru), the Intel HD graphics driver is preloaded and utilizes the MESA driver rather than its own driver. I do know, however, that Intel HD graphics work out of the box. In this case, it's just a matter of switching over to it with the ATI control panel.

Comment: Can I switch between the graphics cards through ATI control panel, because I don't see any options for that purpose. Could you please elaborate.

Comment: I found a couple more links that may be useful to you: [Ubuntu Wiki RadeonDriver (Power Management Section)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver#Power_Management) for using open source Radeon graphics driver and [Ubuntu Wiki BinaryDriverHowto/AMD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD#Manually_installing_Catalyst_13.4.2C_special_case_for_Intel.2BAC8-AMD_hybrid_graphics) for proprietary drivers